# What is causing my Windows 10 computer to crash?

Tags: windows-10, crash

On January this year [I built a new computer for coding and gaming](https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/b/QCmqqs) with the following hardware:

- Asus - X99-DELUXE II ATX LGA2011-3 Motherboard
- 4x G.Skill - Ripjaws 4 series 32GB (4 x 8GB) DDR4-3000 Memory
- Intel - 750 Series 1.2TB PCI-E Solid State Drive
- EVGA - GeForce GTX 1080 8GB FTW Hybrid Gaming Video Card

The system was never stable. I'm experiencing a blue screen of death about every other week and sometimes it fails to boot with q-code 61, which stands for NVRAM Initializing.

I talked to Asus who told me the motherboard was defective because the MemOK! button was not doing something (although the behavior of card matched the manual and not the tech support person). I returned the X99-DELUXE II and got an Asus X99E WS hopping for *workstation quality*. This is my main working tool after all.

Lo and behold, the problem persisted. Since I had enough RAM, I removed half of it and I've been rotating it to try to identify a bad DIMM, but so far, I cannot really attribute the crashes to a particular one.

The computer was re-installed at some point and I was very careful what drivers I was putting on it. This made no difference.

These are the last 5 crashes:

[image]

and this is the q-code log of a stuck boot (it happens sometimes):

```
Power ON 
0000:34 
0002:57 
0003:34 
0006:01 
0004:48 
0C14:01 
0C11:0E 
0C17:18 
0C18:06 
0C21:01 
0C23:01 
0C28:0F 
0C29:02 
0C25:FF 
0C26:BB 
0C2A:2D 
0C2B:01 
0CE0:15 
0C41:63 
0C19:FF 
0CA1:01 
0CA7:02 
0CA9:01 
0CAA:01 
0CAF:01 
0C2F:67 
0CBF:01 
0CB0:FF 
0CB1:15 
0CAF:-- 
RESET 
0000:FF 
0002:51 
0003:34 
0006:01 
0004:47 
0C14:01 
0C11:0E 
0C17:19 
0C18:06 
0C21:01 
0C27:01 
0C28:0E 
0CFF:01 
0C29:02 
0C25:FF 
0C26:B8 
0C2A:2D 
0C2B:01 
0CEB:01 
0CE0:0D 
0C41:62 
0C19:FF 
0CA1:01 
0CA3:01 
0CA7:01 
0CA9:03 
0CA7:01 
0CA9:01 
0CAA:01 
0CAF:02 
0C2F:69 
0CB0:FF 
0CB1:9F 
0CB4:02 
0CB2:01 
0CB3:1D 
0CB6:96 
0CB7:03 
0CBE:01 
0CB7:05 
0CBA:01 
0CB7:01 
0CBB:02 
0CBC:01 
0CBF:1B 
0CAF:-- 
RESET 
0000:FF 
0002:51 
0003:34 
0006:01 
0004:46 
0C14:01 
0011:01 
0C11:01 
0011:01 
0C11:07 
0C13:01 
0C17:16 
0C18:05 
0C23:01 
0C28:0D 
0C29:02 
0C25:FF 
0C26:BC 
0C2A:2D 
0CEB:01 
0CE0:10 
0C40:01 
0C41:60 
0C19:FF 
0CA1:01 
0CA7:01 
0CA9:01 
0CA7:01 
0CAA:01 
0CAF:01 
0C2F:67 
0CB0:FF 
0CB1:9D 
0CB4:02 
0CB3:1C 
0CB6:95 
0CB7:08 
0CBA:01 
0CB7:01 
0CBB:01 
0CBF:FF 
0C3F:01 
0C33:FF 
0C32:FF 
0C4F:FF 
0C6F:01 
0C60:FF 
0C61:FF 
0C9A:3D 
0C0A:01 
0C03:FF 
0C78:ED 
0CB6:FF 
0C68:FF 
0C78:01 
0C70:FF 
0C79:FF 
0C90:04 
0C91:FF 
0C94:24 
0C95:FF 
0C96:FF 
0C97:04 
0CB2:FF 
0C98:02 
0C9C:FF 
0CBC:01 
0CB4:1D 
0C94:01 
0C9C:02 
0CB4:13 
0C9C:01 
0C99:FF 
0CB9:01 
0CB4:FF 
0C94:01 
0C99:B1 
0CA9:01 
0CA2:FF 
0CA0:01 
0CA2:FF 
0CA0:FF 
0CAD:FF 
0CFB:FF 
0C92:0E 
0CA0:A0 
0CA2:FF 
0C99:01 
0CA9:01 
0CA0:BA 
0CA2:FF 
0C99:02 
0CA0:FF 
0CB1:-- 
Power OFF 
DUMP Finish
```

Any ideas what's going?

Sadly, I don't have hardware laying around to start swapping out parts willy-nilly, but if I have a strong enough reason to swap some part, I'll get a new one and send back the old one for a refund (I cannot afford the downtime). I think the only major parts that I haven't swapped yet are:

- Intel - 750 Series 1.2TB PCI-E Solid State Drive
- EVGA - GeForce GTX 1080 8GB FTW Hybrid Gaming Video Card

They are not cheap to play around with.

Comment: [analyze the dumps with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) and not with this bluescreenview crap

Comment: You can also use WhoCrashed (http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed). It is a lot more user-friendly and useful.